# Upgrade to Node 14 causing : TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer

Tags: node.js, fs

I have my application on Node 12. I tried upgrading it to Node 14 and I get this error

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received type number (94)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1517:5)
    at writePid (/app/node_modules/forever/bin/monitor:13:6)
    at exports.Monitor.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/forever/bin/monitor:46:5)
    at exports.Monitor.EventEmitter.emit (/app/node_modules/eventemitter2/lib/eventemitter2.js:339:22)
    at /app/node_modules/forever-monitor/lib/forever-monitor/monitor.js:177:10
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

I noticed that I'm not using fs.writeFileSync in my application, so I'm confused how and where this error is triggered from. How can I debug this?

Comment: Any chance you are using [`forever`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) and you might have an outdated version of it?

Comment: @derpirscher, yes, I am. Would that be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

There was a change in the way how `fs.writeFileSync` treats invalid parameters (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options  and expand the History to see the changes)

Prior to v14 it silently converted unsupported types for `data` to string. Seems it throws an error now. And the version of forever you have installed sends a `number` as data which is not supported. Thus the error. Update to the lastest version of forever.

**EDIT** please also keep in mind the follwing comment on the forever project page

> A simple CLI tool for ensuring that a given script runs continuously (i.e. forever). Note that this project currently fully depends on the community for implementing fixes and new features. For new installations we encourage you to use pm2 or nodemon

Answer (score 0):

You use forever version < 3.0.0. To use forever with nodejs version >= 14.x.x you must upgrade forever to v3.0.0 at least. By testing this bug is fixed in v3.0.0 although author does not mention it in changelog: https://github.com/foreversd/forever/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300--fri-22-may-2020

Note that using forever on nodejs => 14.x.x you will see warning `Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency` but forever is working.